# Laravel query with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, request, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I need to get all "Prestation" datas where status is "Disponible" and get the "first_name" and "last_name" of the Items User concerned.

I have three tables, the first is "Prestations" :

- _id
- name
- price
- created_at
- updated_at

The second is "Items" where i only need to test the status :

- _id
- quantity
- **status** <<<<---- "Disponible"
- **prestation_id**
- **user_id**

The last table is "Users" where i need the first_name and last_name:

- _id
- first_name
- last_name

***Prestation.php*** model :

```
public function item()
 {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item');
 }
```

***Item.php*** model :

```
public function prestation()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Prestation');
}
```

***User.php model***

```
public function items()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Item');
}
```

I read the Laravel documentation and tried something like :

```
/**
//  * @param Request $request
//  * @return mixed
//  */
 public function prestationsListAvailables(Request $request, $conciergerie_select_id = null) 
 {
     $available = 'Disponible';

     $prestations = Prestation::with('item')
         ->whereHas('item', function($query) use ($available) {
             $query->whereIn('status', $available);
         })
         ->get();

     return $prestations;
 }
```

But at this step, nothing works.
I tried simply this too and it's work :

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function prestationsListAvailables(Request $request, $conciergerie_select_id = null) 
{
    $prestations = Prestation::with([
    ])
    ->get();

    return $prestations;
}
```

Here i get all of "Prestations" but i need to test if the status is disponible and get the first_name and last_name of the user concerned.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
/**
//  * @param Request $request
//  * @return mixed
//  */
 public function prestationsListAvailables(Request $request, $conciergerie_select_id = null) 
 {
     $available = 'Disponible';

     $prestations = Prestation::whereHas('item', function($query) use ($available) {
             $query->where('status', $available);
         })
         ->join('items', 'items.prestation_id', '=', 'prestations.id')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')
         ->get([
             'prestations.*',
             'users.firstname AS firstname',
             'users.lastname AS lastname'
         ]);

     return $prestations;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thank's for your suggest, the 'status' treatment looks to be Okay but i get only the prestation id and not the firstname and lastname.
I tried to change the "lastname" and "firstname" with "last_name" and "first_name" but same result.

Comment: Try to use a "select" statment (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects) to define the returned values and use simply ->get();

Comment: Same result with :
     $prestations = Prestation::whereHas('item', function($query) use ($available) {
             $query->where('status', $available);
         })
         ->join('items', 'items.prestation_id', '=', 'prestations.id')
         ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')
         ->select([
             'prestations.*',
             'users.first_name AS firstname',
             'users.last_name AS lastname'
         ])
         ->get();

Answer (score 0):

I would create a belongsToMany relation between User and Item:

Presentation

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'items')->withPivot(['status','quantity']);
}
```

Then you can query the relation with:

```
Presentation::with(['users' => function ($query) use ($available) {
    $query->where('status', $available); // you are filtering the pivot table
}])->get();
```